# Tabular Report - Dynamically Compare Entered Dates and Existing Dates for that Particular User

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex

Using Oracle Apex Version - 4.2

We Have a Tab Called – Input a Claim

Clicking on Add Row Button to Input a Claim Shows two Columns, Start Date and End Date.  User Will enter Start Date and End Date and Click Save.

The Record will be Saved for Particular Period. Ex: April 1st - April 10th. User can Add Multiple Claims by Clicking Add Row Button and Save. Currently User is able to Claim for In between Dates.

We are Trying to Avoid Duplicate Claims from the User. User Should not be able to Enter the Same Date Range or In between Dates.

We are Using Tabular Column and We Want to `Dynamically` **Compare the Entered Dates and Existing Dates for that Particular User** and When if there is a match between entered and existing date/date range we should alert the user.

Ex:

Same Date Range:  April 1st - April 10th

In Between Dates: April 3rd - April 7th

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, `Dynamically` means you do not want to submit the page in order to display the alert. You want to use a dynamic action.

If that is the case, then one way to approach it is to follow these steps:

- You need to remove/set to never the default insert statement/Auto Row Process that is created when you created the tabular form.
- Create your own dynamic action of the type PL/SQL, that inserts the row into the database.
- Create `BEFORE INSERT TRIGGER` on your table, the trigger should compare both columns, the user ID and the period, and raise application exception, if the same user ID is inserting within same period twice. Alternatively, you can create a function that does the comparison and return the TRUE/FALSE
- Based on the returned value, you can display the alert.

I am sure there are other ways to do. But this what came to my mind first.

Comment: Thanks For the Solution.

Comment: When Moved the Cursor to the Next Column it Should Show the Error in Pop Up Alert. I was Able to Implement the Validations to Check END DATE is Not Less Than Start Date When Moved the Cursor to the Next Column, But not able to Do the Same for Dates.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you here. Do you have problem how to display alert? or you have problem how to return TRUE/FALSE? Your PL/SQL function should return either TRUE or FALSE. If you have problems with the function logic, please post another question and tag pl/sql.

Comment: We Fixed it by Creating Trigger as you Mentioned. It is Working Fine. Thank You.